# How can i add multiple dataset in chart.js package in Laravel

Tags: laravel, chart.js

How can i add multiple dataset in [nsoleTVs/Charts](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts) charts.js package in laravel.
my single dataset code is running well:

```
$data['transactionChart'] = new TransactionChart();
        $data['transactionChart']->dataset('Sample', 'line',[100, 65, 84, 45, 90])
            ->options(['borderColor' => '#97d881']);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Simply use ->dataset() multiple times.

https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts/issues/331

Example:

```
$data['transactionChart'] = new TransactionChart();
$data['transactionChart']->dataset('Sample', 'line',[100, 65, 84, 45, 90])
            ->options(['borderColor' => '#97d881']);

$data['transactionChart']->dataset('Another Sample', 'line',[100, 65, 84, 45, 90])
            ->options(['borderColor' => '#ff0000']);
```